# CSS 3D buggy hover issue

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm having trouble with a simple 3D transform:

http://jsfiddle.net/2uFuh

when I hover the cursor on any link everything goes well, but when I slowly move the cursor pixel by pixel accross the link the hover goes nuts, it start oscillating between hover and non-hover!

I really have no clue why it behaves like that...

CSS:

```
header nav a, header nav a:after, header nav a:before {
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px 10px 10px 10px;
}

header nav a, header nav a:before {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

header nav a {
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 8px;
  perspective: 9999px;
  -moz-perspective: 9999;;
  -webkit-perspective: 9999px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-15px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-15px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-15px);
  transform-origin: center center -15px;
  -moz-transform-origin: center center -15px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center -15px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
}

header nav a:after, header nav a:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  content: attr(data-label);
}

header nav a:after, header nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

header nav a:after {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(15px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(15px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(15px);
}

header nav a:before {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(15px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(15px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(15px);
}

header nav a:hover {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-15px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-15px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-15px);
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#/link-1" data-label="Link #1">Link #1</a>
    <a href="#/link-2" data-label="Link #2">Link #2</a>
    <a href="#/link-3" data-label="Link #3">Link #3</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever worked on electronic and circuitry?  Ever hear of keybounce?  Its a condition when you first start to make contact, you have make/break/make in fast action.  Its something you can see on an oscilloscope.  If you are designing logic circuits you have to take that into account in your hardware or software. (Think Arduino and what not...)

In this case, the accuracy of the mouse pointer matters.  Are you in or out of the object of interest? When you cross a threshold with the mouse pointer, what algorithms are used to determine wither you are inside or outside the boundary?  I'm guessing that is based on the browser implementation.  But you are right, it just doesn't look pretty in dynamic form.

By the way, that's a very cool technique for straight CSS.  Nice work.  Thanks for sharing.

Update: I just checked the same jfiddle in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on my mac.  Chrome is MUCH smoother.  Safari has the best appearance in mouse off mode.  (you can NOT see the letters on the 'bottom' of the block at all... in the other two browsers you can just see a hint of black and white, looks odd)  I think you are at the mercy of the browser implementations of HTML here...

Comment: yea, I'm familiar with that! for push buttons I would just put a small capacitor to avoid the oscilation :)
I really don't understand why the browser triggers mouseout if the cursors it's still between the boundaries of the element.

Comment: Gib, to use your words "if the cursors it's still between the boundaries of the element." What it the boundary of the element?  How is it defined?  What algorithm is used to determine when you cross that boundary? I'm quite sure that algorithm (written into the browser's code) is not simple set up for horizontal box.. I'm guessing its going to be more generic to accomodate multi-shaped forms. The issue is, when did you cross the boundary?  Remember http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm   Exact isn't exact.  I'm guessing jQuery may have the 'switch debounce' thing figured out.

Comment: well, the expected behavior is that once the cursor is inside the yellow area the :hover should be triggered, and it does, but for some odd reason while moving the cursor inside the gray area it triggers the mouseout. if the :hover was attached only to the yellow face I would understand, but that's not the case, it's attached to the whole element, thus both faces, yellow and gray.

Answer (score 0):

this explains why it behaves like that:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css3-animations-the-hiccups-and-bugs-youll-want-to-avoid/

in "Pseudo Elements and Z-index" I found:

> (...) You can’t use animations or transitions on pseudo
>   elements. This fact is somewhat poorly documented on the web, but it’s
>   an important one. Let’s say, for instance, you wanted an :after pseudo
>   element to fade into visibility when you hover over it’s parent.
>   Unfortunately, it’ll snap between states instead of transitioning
>   gracefully. (...)

that's such a shame because I'll have to put elements just for that instead of using `:before` and `:after`.

Answer (score 0):

*A little too late to the party but in case for someone who will look forward for this...*

Somehow it works if you are hovering over the parent element.

### Changes

So your html may be like this:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <span class="toFocus">
      <a href="#/link-1" data-label="Link #1">Link #1</a>
    </span>
     <span class="toFocus">
     <a href="#/link-2" data-label="Link #2">Link #2</a>
     </span>
      <span class="toFocus">
    <a href="#/link-3" data-label="Link #3">Link #3</a>
    </span>
  </nav>
</header>
```

And changes in css would be:

```
header nav .toFocus:hover a {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-15px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-15px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-15px);
}
```

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/2uFuh/12/